# Windows 10 password recovery

Tags: windows-10

Last night my brother upgraded his laptop to Windows 10 and when he was trying to import some pictures from his phone it was asking us to create an account.

So we did and everything seemed to be fine until we we restarted the computer. It asked for the password and whenever I entered the password that he used it says **wrong password**.

I tried the recover option but it turned to be that this email already belongs to someone else.

How is that even possible?

Basically I can't do the recovery via email or phone number because I am not in control of those accounts.

How could it be possible to make an account that was already used in the first place?

Comment: This is a great example for why periods have been invented.

Comment: He couldn't.  Be sure he is using the password to the Microsoft Account and not the original password to the local account.  If you still cannot access the user account, enable the default Administrator account, and create a new user profile.

Comment: I highly suspect you mistyped the password twice and are facing the consequences..

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me see if I get this right.

You created a Microsoft Account with a password. When you restarted on the login screen it will say the username and an E-mail Address below it. 
It would be what is blurred out in this picture:

[image: Example]

Ensure that that is the correct E-Mail address you made. If not then it sounds as though you are logging into a local account and the last password you setup for the computer before the upgrade should work. If it is the correct e-mail you can use another computer and go to http://account.live.com and you can test the E-Mail and password.

If the password is incorrect then use their "FORGOT PASSWORD" link to reset you password. Then plug your computer into a network connection and restart it and try and login with the new password providing the E-Mail is correct. That should reach out to Microsoft for the latest password and allow you access in.